# unable to access global redis in a Sidekiq job via sidekiq-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

We are thinking of moving from resque-scheduler to sidekiq-scheduler. We have a reference to a global $redis instance but in our job, we are not able to access it, like the following.

```
require 'sidekiq-scheduler'

class HelloWorld
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    $redis.incr(Time.new.strftime("hello-world-%Y-%m-%d"))
    puts 'Hello world'
  end
end
```

Our $redis is instantiated in config/initializers/00_redis.rb like

`$redis = Redis.new`

which I can access from a rails console. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does "not able to access it" mean?